# Wrong values after first cout

Tags: c++, windows

I'm making a test program for starting with C++ :)

It's showing wrong values after first print

[image]

This is the code (very simple)

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int varInt = 123456;
    char varString[] = "DefaultString";
    char arrChar[128] = "Long char array right there ->";
    int * ptr2int;
    ptr2int = &varInt;
    int ** ptr2ptr;
    ptr2ptr = &ptr2int;
    int *** ptr2ptr2;
    ptr2ptr2 = &ptr2ptr;

    while(1){
        cout << "Process ID: " << GetCurrentProcessId() << endl;

        cout << "varInt (0x" << &varInt << ") = " << varInt << endl;
        cout << "varString (0x" << &varString << ") = " << varString << endl;
        cout << "varChar (0x" << &arrChar << ") = " << arrChar << endl;

        cout << "ptr2int (0x" << hex << &ptr2int << ") = " << ptr2int << endl;
        cout << "ptr2ptr (0x" << hex << &ptr2ptr << ") = " << ptr2ptr << endl;
        cout << "ptr2ptr2 (0x" << hex << &ptr2ptr2 << ") = " << ptr2ptr2 << endl;

        cout << "Press ENTER to print again." << endl;
        getchar();
        cout << "-----------------------------------" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The expected results are obvious, as the code is published as is:

- `Process ID` is integer so should return `12704` (or any int value) instead of `31a0`
- `varInt` it's also integer and should return `123456` instead of `1e240`

Comment: `std::hex` IO-manipulator is sticky, once you use it the stream will output following up integer number in hexadecimal format.

Comment: Instead of editing your question, with the solution, you could either add another answer (if you think that's really necessary), or mark the answer that helped you most as accepted (like you already did). Your **SOLVED** edit is just noise and not necessary.

Comment: alright, I'm sorry, just cleaning now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1e240 is the same thing as 123456 in hex. The first iteration will print 123456 correctly but after you set the base flag of cout to hex mode, you need to set it back to dec to print 123456 again on the next loop.

```
cout << "varInt (0x" << &varInt << ") = " << dec << varInt << endl;
```

See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/hex/) for documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the correct answer and the link for more information :)

Comment: If you're coming from a different language, cout is a lot different that other "print" statements that you're used to. It is a stream with formatting parameters bound to it.